# Date-month conversion in Excel

Tags: excel

Having a date as 15/8/2022 and i need to add the month value to date as 15-Aug-2022 using Excel. Can someone please help me?

Expected output:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on cells, choose "Format cells...". In "Number" tab choose "Date" category and scroll until you find your desired format. Select and press "Ok":

[image]

Comment: Is there any formula for doing that?

Comment: @ammuanu you can use Text Function , =TEXT("05/03/2023","dd-mmm-yy")